# Perform multiple regex operations on each line of text file and store extracted data in respective column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, python-re

**Data in test.txt**

```
<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>DXB</CityCode><CountryCode>EG</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>TA</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>95HAJSTI</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></ServiceRQ>

<SearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>CPT</CityCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>AY</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>56ASJSTS</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></SearchRQ>

<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>BOM</CityCode><CountryCode>AU</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>QA</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>85ATAKSQ</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></ServiceRQ>

<ServiceRQ ......

<SearchRQ ........
```

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
columns = ['Request Type','Channel','AG']
# data = pd.DataFrame
exp = re.compile(r'<(.*)\s+xmlns'
                 r'<Channel>(.*)</Channel>'
                 r'<Param Name="AG">.*?<Value>(.*?)</Value>')
final = []
with open(r"test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = re.search(exp,line)
        final.append(result)

    df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns)
    print(df)
```

**My expected output is**
I want to iterate through each line and to perform the 3 regex operation and extract data from each line in text file

```
1. r'<(.*)\s+xmlns'
2. r'<Channel>(.*)</Channel>'
3. r'<Param Name="AG">.*?<Value>(.*?)</Value>')
```

Each regex extract respective data from single line
like

1. extract the type of request
2. extract the name of channel
3. extract the value present for **AG**

**My expected output ExcelSheet**

```
Request Type    Channel       AG
ServiceRQ         TA        95HAJSTI  
SearchRQ          AY        56ASJSTS
ServiceRQ         QA        85ATAKSQ
 ...              ...         .....
 ...              ....        .....
and so on..
```

How can I achieve expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `re`, actually I don't Know how the rest of your text content looks like, but this will work with what I have seen so far.
[`result.groups()`](https://pynative.com/python-regex-capturing-groups/) will extract matching elements of all groups then return a tuple before appending.

```py
exp = re.compile(r'<(\w+)\s+xmlns.*?>.*?'
                 r'<Channel>(.*?)</Channel>.*?'
                 r'<Param Name="AG"><Value>(.*?)</Value>')
final = []
with open(r"test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = re.search(exp,line)
        if result:
            final.append(result.groups())
            
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

**Test code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

columns = ['Request Type','Channel','AG']

file_data = """
<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>DXB</CityCode><CountryCode>EG</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>TA</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>95HAJSTI</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></ServiceRQ>
<SearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>CPT</CityCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>AY</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>56ASJSTS</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></SearchRQ>
<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>BOM</CityCode><CountryCode>AU</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>QA</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>85ATAKSQ</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></ServiceRQ>
"""

exp = re.compile(r'<(\w+)\s+xmlns.*?>.*?'
                 r'<Channel>(.*?)</Channel>.*?'
                 r'<Param Name="AG"><Value>(.*?)</Value>')
final = []
for line in file_data.splitlines():
    result = re.search(exp,line)
    if result:
        final.append(result.groups())
        
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

---

```
  Request Type Channel        AG
0    ServiceRQ      TA  95HAJSTI
1     SearchRQ      AY  56ASJSTS
2    ServiceRQ      QA  85ATAKSQ
```

Comment: Hello Jamiu, I am getting below error.
`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (27, 1), indices imply (27, 3)`

Comment: Try: `file_lines = f.readlines()` then  `for line in file_lines:` Just like I said earlier if that fails then something is wrong with your data. I will add a test at the bottom of my existing answer with the first 3 lines of your data to confirm that the code works.